# Remove @VisibleForTesting using proguard in production build

Tags: android, android-testing, android-proguard

As far as I know, @VisibleForTesting is used to modify the scope of methods or variables for testing purpose in Android. But these annotations are not required in the production build. However, the annotations are not removed by default. Is there any way to remove them? Maybe using proguard?

Also can anyone tell me why the retention policy of this annotation is CLASS?